# Why OpenCV RGB to YCbCr conversion doesn't give the same result as conversion in matlab using ycbcr2rgb function?

Tags: matlab, opencv, rgb, color-conversion

I am trying to replicate my matlab code into C with OpenCV. Here I have a step where I need to convert the image from rgb to ycbcr and do histogram equalization. But the results of both in matlab and C are very different.

I am using Matlab R2016b and OpenCV 4.0.0

Which one is the correct way to do and why I am seeing this difference?

Steps I am following in MATLAB and C are stated below:

C Steps:

1. Read an Image frame in RGB using imread()
2. Converted the RGB image to YCBCr using cv::cvtColor()
3. Checked the values of Y channel

   `cv::Mat image, ycbcr;
   vector splitted;
   image = imread("image_name.jpg");
   cv::cvtColor(image, ycbcr, COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
   cv::split(ycbcr, splitted)
   cv::equalizeHist(splitted[0],splitted[0]);
   cv::merge(dst_host,ycbcr);
   cv::cvtColor(ycbcr, image, COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);
   imshow("Equalized", image);`

MATLAB steps:

1. Read an Image frame in RGB using imread()
2. Converted the RGB image to YCBCr using rgb2ycbcr()
3. Checked the values of Y channel

   `im = imread('image_name.jpg');
   ycbcr_im = rgb2ycbcr(im);
   ycbcr_im(:,:,1) = histeq(ycbcr_im(:,:,1));
   im = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcr_im);
   imshow(im);`

So I checked the results after converting from rgb to ycbcr in OpenCV and MATLAB and the result are different in the conversion itself.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: You cannot read an image in RGB in OpenCV using `imread()`. You will get BGR, and must use the corresponding `cvtColor()` with BGR in it.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That is not what your question says...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using COLOR_BGR2YCrCb macro. This is the code to convert from RGB to YCbCr in OpenCV. cv::cvtColor(src,dst,COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

Comment: Please put your code in your question where it is formatted and easy to read, then correct your question so we can help you, and other people reading your question, more easily. Click `edit` under your question to do that and use `{}` button in formatting toolbar to identify code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the documentation of OpenCV and Matlab color conversion. I found the following. In my observation, there is a major difference in the algorithm and implementation.

In Matlab,
the rgb2ycbcr() function converts the color in digital formula which is

```
Y = 16+ (65.481 * R + 128.553 * G + 24.966 * B)
Cb = 128+ (-37.797 * R - 74.203 * G + 112.0 * B)
Cr = 128+ (112.0 * R - 93.786 * G - 18.214 * B)
```

If the input is uint8, then YCBCR is uint8 where Y is in the range [16 235], and Cb and Cr are in the range [16 240].

But in OpenCV,
the conversion is done in analog formula which is,

```
Y = 0.299 * R+ 0.587 * G+ 0.114 * B
Cb = -0.168736 * R - 0.331264 * G + 0.5 * B
Cr = 0.5 * R - 0.418688 * G - 0.081312 * B
```

If the input is uint8, then YCBCR is uint8 where Y  and Cb and Cr are in the range [0 255]. This is the reason why you are getting a different result.

Comment: One is for video/television (first, restricted range), and the second for photos (full range).